# Directory structure for TypeScript projects

Tags: typescript, directory-structure, conventions, typescript1.8

What would be an idiomatic directory structure for a TypeScript project?

I would like the following features in such a structure:

1. Separate directories for TypeScript source code and transpiled JavaScript
2. Separate directories for project source code and test code
3. Mechanism to resolve references across tests and source code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Separating generated JS from source TS

I would recommend generating a single-file output. Be it browser or for Node, its just a better idea. Bear in mind that most IDEs can hide `.gitignore`d files, so an uncluttered file-pane *shouldn't* be a problem to attain, even if you let the `.js` files sit right next to their `.ts` files.

You *can* technically use [`--outDir`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to output the way you want by setting up your `tsconfig.json` appropriately.

### Separating tests from source

This is fairly trivial! Just maintain a `/tests`. Imports work simply by directory traversal like so `import {MyClass} from "../src/modules/my-class"` (where the `../` is to get out of `/tests`).

### Mechanism to resolve references

This is more challenging in the browser than on Node — the latter has `require`s working out of the box for TypeScript.

#### On the browser

Strongly recommend you go with something like `webpack`, but if you insist on living life on the dangerous side, here is a browser-friendly require that I use to rapidly iterate on TypeScript code without having a build process setup.

[`require()` for the browser](https://gist.github.com/angadn/b553fdc09e56bcb9aeaa)

- **Not for the weak hearted — *this is tech debt you will accumulate***

Since absolute paths are necessary for working web imports, here is how you can use my `require()` hack with TypeScript (typically for a fast debugging session that doesn't require rebuilding).

`/entities/user.ts`

```
import {Username} from "../entities/username";
import {Password} from "../entities/password";

export class User {
    username: Username;
    password: Password;
}
```

Where `Username` and `Password` are `export`ed classes in `/entities/username.ts` and `/entities/password.ts` respectively.

While the `../entities/` might seem extraneous, notice that it is essential for the browser to have appropriate absolute paths to our `Username` and `Password` entities. :)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Your post led me to find a solution.

Comment: I am now revisiting this in 2020. Would be grateful to anyone who reminds me why I was so sure that generating single-file output for Node is a good idea 

Comment: @Angad is generating single file for node a bad idea ?Can you elaborate?

Comment: @JanCiołek Hmm, I don't think it's a bad idea for sure! It's really a question of motivation - so far in my projects other than when WebPacking for the browser, I've not had the motivation to generating a single-file output. It significantly complicates debugging so unless you need it, I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like I was doing it wrong. I was trying the following structure:

```
src
|---- lib
|-----|---- mymodule.ts
|---- tests
|-----|---- mymodule.tests.ts
```

However, I was attempting to compile the source code under `lib` directory separately from the test code under `tests`.

`find src/lib -name *.ts | xargs tsc --declaration --sourceMap --module commonjs --target es5 --listFiles --outDir lib`

and then the tests code:

`find src/tests -name *.ts | xargs tsc --declaration --sourceMap --module commonjs --target es5 --listFiles --outDir tests`

This caused the `tests` folder to have another `lib` sub-directory and a `tests` sub-directory. This was not what I intended to have.

To solve my problem I needed to compile them together, so now my command is:

`find src -name *.ts | xargs tsc --declaration --sourceMap --module commonjs --target es5 --listFiles --outDir .`

Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: Thanks. I've now structured my project the same way with a tsconfig.json placed in the src folder and I just run "tsc -p ./src" to get everything to compile.

Comment: Just a heads-up, it is fairly simple to automate creation of `tsconfig.json` using the right tools, such as `Atom TypeScript` on Atom. Would strongly recommend you to check it out if you haven't already - choosing a particular directory-structure because of build process sounds like the beginning of a  readability-debt :)

Answer (score 3):

It is very hard to give any concrete advice, since this hugely depends on the project size, tools, platform etc.

1. Typescript compiler has a `--outDir` option which you can use to output to separate directory. However, you would also probably like to bundle so output to single file might be more preferable, as long as you create *map* files as well for debugging. You can structure all of this very nicely with Gulp for example.
2. What does this have to do with directory structure? If you want to split it, then split it
3. "Mechanism" is very wide, and depends on the tools you use. For example, the test runner might be able to "import" production code before the test code. You could use some module loading library as well etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is an evolving thing for me, but for node projects I am setting up an /src and /dist directory using tsconfig outDir to point to the dist directory:

```
/root
  |__dist/
  |__src/
  |____lib/
  |____etc...
```

For absolute paths, I use "imports" in package.json:

```
"imports": {
    "#src/*": "./dist/*",
    "#lib/*": "./dist/lib/*",
    "#root/*": "./*"
  },
```

keep in mind that when it transpiles, it does not touch the import statements which means you need to write them from the perspective of the js code that is created.  For me, I feel like it makes more logical sense when developing to write imports from the src/ perspective, which is why you see a src/ mapping to dist/.

Personally, I set the package.json type to module for the more modern imports/exports (even though I know it can transpile to commonJS style require modules), and I target for the latest ES version - reasoning being that if it's just back-end code anyway, I care a lot less about backewards compatibility with older node versions.

The one thing that's kind of annoying is the lack of any built-in cleaning solution for the dist folder if you are using the --watch flag, but personally I just set up nodemon to watch the src/ directory and then run something like:

```
"scripts": {"dev-watch": "nodemon --watch src --ext \"*\" --exec \"tsc && node dist/app.js\""}
```